# GPU support for TensorFlow & PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, gpu

Okay, so I've worked on a bunch of Deep Learning projects and internships now and I've never had to do heavy training. But lately I've been thinking of doing some Transfer Learning for which I'll need to run my code on a GPU. Now I have a system with Windows 10 and a dedicated NVIDIA GeForce 940M GPU. I've been doing a lot of research online, but I'm still a bit confused. I haven't installed the NVIDIA Cuda Toolkit or cuDNN or tensorflow-gpu on my system yet. I currently use tensorflow and pytorch to train my DL models. Here are my queries -

1. When I define a tensor in tf or pytorch, it is a cpu tensor by default. So, all the training I've been doing so far has been on the CPU. So, if I make sure to install the correct versions of Cuda and cuDNN and tensorflow-gpu (specifically for tensorflow), I can run my models on my GPU using tf-gpu and pytorch and that's it? (I'm aware of the torch.cuda.is_available() in pytorch to ensure pytorch can access my GPU and the device_lib module in tf to check if my gpu is visible to tensorflow)(I'm also aware of the fact that tf doesnt support all Nvidia GPUs)
2. Why does tf have a separate module for GPU support? PyTorch doesnt seem to have that and all you need to do is cast your tensor from cpu() to cuda() to switch between them.
3. Why install cuDNN? I know it is a high-level API CUDA built for support to train Deep Neural Nets on the GPU. But do tf-gpu and torch use these in the backend while training on the gpu?
4. After tf == 1.15, did they combine CPU and GPU support all into one package?

Answer (score 1):

First of all unfortunately 940M is a kinda weak GPU for training. I suggest you use Google colab for faster training but of course, it would be faster than the CPU. So here my answers to your four questions.

1-) Yes if you install the requirements correctly, then you can run on GPU. You can manually place your data to your GPU as well. You can check implementations on TensorFlow. In PyTorch, you should specify the device that you want to use. As you said you should do `device = torch.device("cuda" if args.cuda else "cpu")` then for models and data you should always call `.to(device)` Then it will automatically use GPU if available.

2-) PyTorch also needs extra installation (module) for GPU support. However, with recent updates both TF and PyTorch are easy to use for GPU compatible code.

3-) Both Tensorflow and PyTorch is based on cuDNN. You can use them without cuDNN but as far as I know, it hurts the performance but I'm not sure about this topic.

4-) No they are still different packages. `tensorflow-gpu==1.15 and tensorflow==1.15` what they did with tf2, was making the tensorflow more like Keras. So it is more simplified then 1.15 or before.

Comment: in your second answer, what do you mean PyTorch also needs extra installation? I'm assuming you mean installing compatible versions of Cuda and cuDNN with PyTorch right?

Comment: @vikram71198 yes for cuda you should install different PyTorch module (e.g torch==1.6.0+cu101). I am not sure cuDNN is a prerequisite but cudatoolkit is.

Answer (score 0):

Rest was already answered by regarding 3) cudNN optimizes layer and such operations on hardware level and those implementations are pure black magic. It is incredibly hard to write CUDA code that properly utilizes your GPU (how load data into the GPU, how to actually perform them using matrices etc. )